# Is there a bug in preview when using parentheses in link URLs?

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, editor

I would like to report a bug.

If there are parentheses in a URL then the link is incorrect 
in the preview (but not in the final page).

Example, composing an answer to a question on Stack Overflow:

> Of dying programming languages [Forth][1] is one of the best.
>
> [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_(programming_language)

The link to Forth in the preview becomes:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_

Platform: Firefox 3.0.6, Windows XP 64 bit, 8 GB RAM.

Comment: no-repro on OSX Lion / FF12

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Google Chrome 21 for Arch Linux.

Comment: Congratulations on owning the oldest non-deleted question that earned the Tumbleweed badge `:P`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has long been fixed. Not surprising, since this bug report is almost three years old :)